# Readfile error in the download feature on my website

Tags: php, download, ftp, zip, readfile

Hi i am making a download feature on my website and it is running however all the files are corrupted due to a recurring error readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in 'my/file/location'  I don't understand why this is happening because according to every post I have looked at I am doing the download->zipfiles procedure correctly.  Please help.

By the way i think the key to the answer may be in the fact that when i open the zip in a text file it reads:

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(/uploads/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/ghostx19/public_html/phDownloader.php** on line **21**

the error is repeated 10 times because of the loop obviously

My Code:

```
 <?php 
 //define stuff
$dir = "./uploads";
$allfiles = glob($dir.'*.{aiff}', GLOB_BRACE); 

// create zip
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}



//array of random files    
$n=1;
while ($n<=10){
$n ++;
$randomfile = $allfiles[array_rand($allfiles)];
$path = "./uploads".$randomfile;
$zip->addFile(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path)); 
}

// //present for download
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zip_name);
readfile('zipfile.zip');
  if(file_exists('zipfile.zip'))
{
  unlink('zipfile.zip');
}

?>
```

Comment: I doubt the file you posted is really the code creating that archive. The error message does not fit. There is only one `readfile()` usage in the code you posted and that certainly is _not_ repeated 10 times. Can it be the zip file you have is from a much older attempt?

Comment: oh shit my bad it totally is, this is the error i have for the current code above `file_get_contents(/uploads/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/ghostx19/public_html/phDownloader.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />`

Comment: there is 10 though because i am looping this function 10 times so i can upload 10 random files